# Help with computing confidence intervals for zero-hurdle model

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, zero-inflation

I am trying to calculate confidence intervals for the exponentiated coefficients of a hurdle model. I know I can't use the confint function as with normal GLMs, and suspect I have to use some kind of bootstrapping function. From googling this problem the only answer I could find was on this page https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/zinb/ but this is for zero-inflation regression, rather than a zero-hurdle model. I tried to adapt the code they give further down the page for my zero-hurdle model, but it does not work.

f <- function(data, i) {
require(pscl)
m <- hurdle(count ~ child + camper | persons,
data = data[i, ], dist = "negbin",
start = list(count = c(1.3711, -1.5152, 0.879), zero = c(1.6028, -1.6663)))
as.vector(t(do.call(rbind, coef(summary(m)))[, 1:2]))
}

set.seed(10)
(res <- boot(zinb, f, R = 1200, parallel = "snow", ncpus = 4))

parms <- t(sapply(c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9), function(i) {
out <- boot.ci(res, index = c(i, i + 1), type = c("perc", "bca"))
with(out, c(Est = t0, pLL = percent[4], pUL = percent[5],
bcaLL = bca[4], bcaUL = bca[5]))
}))

### add row names

row.names(parms) <- names(coef(m1))

I get the warning message:In norm.inter(t, adj.alpha) : extreme order statistics used as endpoints.
It's probably a long shot that anyone can answer this question but any help would be appreciated!